# How to inject Session/User object after bootstrapping?

Tags: java, gwt, gwtp, gwt-platform

There are examples where different kinds of objects are getting injected into a presenter, but I can't find an explanation how this can be done.

In the [Bootstrap-Code](http://dev.arcbees.com/gwtp/get-started/Bootstrap-Code.html) example they are injecting e.g. a `SecurityDelegate` object.

Also in the [Gatekeeper](http://dev.arcbees.com/gwtp/core/security/) example I see things being injected, e.g. `MyGatekeeper`, but how is this done?

What I want is to first check if the user is logged in and then create a `CurrentSession` object or something like this. But how can I pass/inject this object around?

At the moment I am initializing a singleton object `CurrentUser` which is kind of ugly imho. I would like to get the GWTP support running, but how?

---

Take this example of the `CurrentSession` being injected into the gatekeeper:

```java
@DefaultGatekeeper
public class LoggedInGatekeeper implements Gatekeeper {
    private final CurrentSession currentSession;

    @Inject
    LoggedInGatekeeper(CurrentSession currentSession) {
        this.currentSession = currentSession;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canReveal() {
        return currentSession.isLoggedIn();
    }
}
```

How do I inject `CurrentSession` here?

Comment: Wow, this question survived 20h with completely wrong tags without down-votes :D Sorry for that, I corrected those tags.

Comment: Should be bumped. It seems either nobody knows or missed this.

Comment: @EdvinTenovim Nobodoy knows. Fantastic! XD

Comment: Yea... :/ Unfortunately, I don't know either (have no idea). And this bounty... It's a pity if it goes away.

Comment: @EdvinTenovim Yeah, I the bounty is not that important to me. It's a bit hard seeing that not a lot people seem to use GWTP nowadays :/ That's the worst thing .. ^^

Comment: Yeah, sorry to hear about that. But I'm sure you will be able to find the answer. :) Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tutorial that explains how to use Gatekeeper : http://dev.arcbees.com/gwtp/tutorials/tutorial-part2.html

Declare CurrentSession's class ( CurrentUser in the tutorial ) as Singleton in your Gin's module like below :

```
public class YourGinModule extends AbstractGinModule {

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind( CurrentSession.class ).in ( Singleton.class );
        ...
    }

}
```

Here you can find another example using GWTP Gatekeeper on client side and Spring Security on server side : https://github.com/imrabti/gwtp-spring-security